# How does one import local Ghost CMS to AWS EC2

Tags: content-management-system, ghost-blog

I've been working on blog using Ghost CMS and having difficulty uploading my local files to the server. I'm unexperienced using terminal and wondering if someone can help point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of guides on [How To Install Ghost](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/) that may help.  If you could provide more information I am sure we could help you more.

- What hosting provider are you using
- at what point during the upload process did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Also if you'd like step-by-step tutorials with screenshots, feel free to check out [Ghost For Beginners](http://www.ghostforbeginners.com).

But just a question from me, before I could elaborate more on your question:
What server are you using? Is this a VPS, or is it on the cloud?